# How to avoid remote memory allocation in numa architecture?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, numa, numactl

I have a numa machine with two nodes, each node has 8 cores and 64G memory and have two services: service-1 and service-2, service-1 deployed in node-0, and service-2 deployed in node-1.

I just want these two services to run separately, So I start service as followed:

```
numactl --membind=0 ./service-1

numactl --membind=1 ./service-2
```

In service code, I use pthread_setaffinity_np to bind threads to corresponding node's cpus(binding service-1 to cpu[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]);

```
localhost:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31


localhost:~$ numactl -H
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22
node 0 size: 64327 MB
node 0 free: 17231 MB
node 1 cpus: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23
node 1 size: 64498 MB
node 1 free: 37633 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10
```

What I expected is linux system allocates memory on node-1 for service-2, besides service-2 visits node-1 memory mainly and some dynamic library pages on node-0. But sadly I find service-2 has a lot of memory on remote node（node-0) and visiting it costs too much time.

```
service-2's numa_maps as followed:

7f07e8c00000 bind:1 anon=455168 dirty=455168 N0=442368 N1=12800
7f08e4200000 bind:1 anon=128000 dirty=128000 N0=121344 N1=6656
7f092be00000 bind:1 anon=21504 dirty=21504 N0=20992 N1=512
7f093ac00000 bind:1 anon=32768 dirty=32768 N0=27136 N1=5632
7f0944e00000 bind:1 anon=82432 dirty=82432 N0=81920 N1=512
7f0959400000 bind:1 anon=1024 dirty=1024 N0=1024
7f0959a00000 bind:1 anon=4096 dirty=4096 N0=4096
7f095aa00000 bind:1 anon=2560 dirty=2560 N0=2560
7f095b600000 bind:1 anon=4608 dirty=4608 N0=4608
7f095c800000 bind:1 anon=512 dirty=512 N0=512
7f095cc00000 bind:1 anon=512 dirty=512 N0=512
...
```

So here are my questions:

1、Does linux system really do allocate remote memory（node-0） for service-2, regardless of service-2 is already bound to node-1 by [membind command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl)?

```cpp
--membind=nodes, -m nodes
Only allocate memory from nodes. Allocation will fail when there is not enough memory available on these nodes. nodes may be specified as noted above.
```

2、Is this associated with [kernel.numa_balancing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/sect-virtualization_tuning_optimization_guide-numa-auto_numa_balancing), which values 1 in my machine? In my opinion, with kernel.numa_balancing = 1, linux only migrates tasks to the nearest memory or move memory to the nearest node where the task was executed. Since service-2 has already bound to node-1, no balancing would happen?

3、Can someone explain how this remote allocation happened? Is there any methods to avoid this?

Thank you very much !

Comment: The problem could be the node where is running service2 at startup. You could bind service2 to node 1 since startup: `numactl --cpunorebind=1 ./service2`.

Comment: Thank you Oliv!  That's really possible. But  `taskset -c -p ${pid}`  shows service-2 is always running on cpus of node-1.